# React context does not update state until the page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

I have a list of patients. I need to display the data of a single patient. The patients are identified uniquely using an id. When I get a particular patient's data from the backend using axios, it seems to work perfectly. But the problem is that I need the state to update to that object when I click on the patient's link. 
 
When I log from the reducer.ts file, the payload loads perfectly. But then, when I click on the link to actually show the data, it does not show it until the page is refreshed. However, after it is refreshed it does change the state to the unique object I want, and then reverts back to the initial state. I want it to get the object and keep it in the state. Where am I going wrong?
Before the page is refreshed:
[image: Before the page is refreshed.]
After the page is refreshed:
[image: After the page is refreshed.]
index.ts:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { reducer, StateProvider } from "./state";

ReactDOM.render(
  <StateProvider reducer={reducer}>
    <App />
  </StateProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Reducer.ts:

```
import { State } from "./state";
import { Patient } from "../types";

export type Action =
  | {
      type: "SET_PATIENT_LIST";
      payload: Patient[];
    }
  | {
      type: "SINGLE_PATIENT";
      payload: Patient;
    };

export const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_PATIENT_LIST":
      return {
        ...state,
        patients: {
          ...action.payload.reduce(
            (memo, patient) => ({ ...memo, [patient.id]: patient }),
            {}
          ),
          ...state.patients
        }
      };
    case "SINGLE_PATIENT":
      console.log(action.payload); 
      return {
        ...state,
        patients: {
          ...state.patients,
          [action.payload.id]:  {
            ...state.patients[action.payload.id],
            ...action.payload,
          },
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const setPatientList = (patientList: Patient[]): Action => {
  return {
    type: "SET_PATIENT_LIST",
    payload: patientList
  };
};

export const setSinglePatient = (patient: Patient): Action => {
  return {
    type: "SINGLE_PATIENT",
    payload: patient
  };
};
```

State.tsx:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { Patient } from "../types";
import { Action } from "./reducer";

export type State = {
  patients: { [id: string]: Patient };
};

const initialState: State = {
  patients: {}
};

export const StateContext = createContext<[State, React.Dispatch<Action>]>([initialState, () => initialState]);

type StateProviderProps = {
  reducer: React.Reducer<State, Action>;
  children: React.ReactElement;
};

export const StateProvider = ({
  reducer,
  children
}: StateProviderProps) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Divider, Container, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import { apiBaseUrl } from "./constants";
import { useStateValue, setPatientList } from "./state";
import { Patient } from "./types";

import PatientListPage from "./PatientListPage";
import SinglePatientPage from "./SinglePatientPage";

const App = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    void axios.get<void>(`${apiBaseUrl}/ping`);

    const fetchPatientList = async () => {
      try {
        const { data: patientListFromApi } = await axios.get<Patient[]>(
          `${apiBaseUrl}/patients`
        );
        dispatch(setPatientList(patientListFromApi));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };

    void fetchPatientList();
  }, [dispatch]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Container>
          <Typography variant="h3" style={{ marginBottom: "0.5em" }}>
            Patientor
          </Typography>
          <Button component={Link} to="/" variant="contained" color="primary">
            Home
          </Button>
          <Divider hidden />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<PatientListPage />} />
            <Route path="/patients/:id" element={<SinglePatientPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

PatientListPage.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Box,
  Table,
  Button,
  TableHead,
  Typography,
  TableCell,
  TableRow,
  TableBody
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { PatientFormValues } from "../AddPatientModal/AddPatientForm";
import AddPatientModal from "../AddPatientModal";
import { Patient } from "../types";
import { apiBaseUrl } from "../constants";
import HealthRatingBar from "../components/HealthRatingBar";
import { useStateValue } from "../state";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PatientListPage = () => {
  const [{ patients }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<string>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box>
        <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
          Patient list
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Table style={{ marginBottom: "1em" }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Gender</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Occupation</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Health Rating</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {Object.values(patients).map((patient: Patient) => (
            <TableRow key={patient.id}>
              <TableCell>
                <Link to={`/patients/${patient.id}`}>
                  {patient.name}
                </Link>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{patient.gender}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{patient.occupation}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <HealthRatingBar showText={false} rating={1} />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PatientListPage;
```

SinglePatientPage:

```
import React from "react";
import { Patient } from "../types";
import { useStateValue, setSinglePatient } from "../state";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { apiBaseUrl } from "../constants";
import axios from "axios";

const SinglePatientPage = () => {
  const [{ patients }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSinglePatient = async () => {
      if(id !== undefined) {
        try {
          const { data: patientFromApi } = await axios.get<Patient>(
            `${apiBaseUrl}/patients/${id}`
          );
          dispatch(setSinglePatient(patientFromApi));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    };
    void fetchSinglePatient();
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (patients) {
    console.log('inside singlepatientpage', patients);
     return (
       <div className="app">
         <Typography variant="h6" style={{ marginBottom: "0.5em" }}>
           {patient.name}
           <p>ssn: {patient.ssn}</p>
           <p>occupation: {patient.occupation}</p>
         </Typography>
       </div>
     );
  }

  return null;
};

export default SinglePatientPage;
```

Comment: Where do you use `StateProvider`?

Comment: I edited the question. I used it in index.ts.

Comment: I don't see where you have shared any code that does anything with a specific patient. Where do you call `setSinglePatient`? If you are seeing the correct data in the reducer function then I suspect that part is correct and you've just an issue in the `SinglePatientPage` component. Please share all relevant code you are working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I hadn't made a new state for singular patient data.

```
export type State = {
  patients: { [id: string]: Patient };
  patient: Patient | null; //new state
};

const initialState: State = {
  patients: {},
  patient: null //new initial state
};
```

And in the reducer, I was returning an array of patients. Now I can return a single patient's data.

```
case "SINGLE_PATIENT":
  return {
    ...state,
    patient: action.payload // returning "patient" instead of "patients"
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `SinglePatientPage` component is missing using the `id` route param as a dependency for fetching the specific patient record.

Add `id` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array since it is referenced in the callback.

```
const SinglePatientPage = () => {
  const [{ patients }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSinglePatient = async () => {
      if(id !== undefined) {
        try {
          const { data: patientFromApi } = await axios.get<Patient>(
            `${apiBaseUrl}/patients/${id}` // <-- id referenced here
          );
          dispatch(setSinglePatient(patientFromApi));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    };
    void fetchSinglePatient();
  }, [dispatch, id]); // <-- add id dependency

  if (!patients) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Typography variant="h6" style={{ marginBottom: "0.5em" }}>
        {patient.name}
        <p>ssn: {patient.ssn}</p>
        <p>occupation: {patient.occupation}</p>
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You might consider adding the [React hooks eslint rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) to your project to help catch missing dependencies like this in the future.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately, it didn't solve it. It still has the same behavior.

Comment: @WildPeace007 I see. There might be something else elsewhere causing the context not to update. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I tried to run it on codesandbox and I could run the frontend. But the backend server is hosted on localhost. Is there any way to run a server on codesandbox?

Comment: @WildPeace007 There *may* be, but it would be ***much*** simpler to just mock any API responses if you know the backend code is returning the correct data.